# How to retrieve related data in order

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data:

- referenced

  - objA
  - objB
  - objC
- order

  - objA: 1
  - objB: 3
  - objC: 2

I want to return objects B, C and A in that order. Is that possible with a firebase query, or do I have to do the sorting on my end once I've received them all?

Here is the code I've tried:

```
 databaseRef.child("order").queryOrderedByValue().observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    let enumerator = snapshot.children
    while let child = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {

        print("queryOrderedByValue: \(child.key)")

        // Get the actual object
        databaseRef.child("referenced/\(child.key)").observe(.value, with: {
            snap in
            print("Received: \(snap.key)")
            })
        })
    }
})
```

But it receives the requested objects out of order, so I end up with:

```
queryOrderedByValue: objA
queryOrderedByValue: objC
queryOrderedByValue: objB
Received: objA
Received: objB
Received: objC
```

Notice that objB and objC are not in the order we requested them.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong and I shouldn't be treating firebase as a relational database, but I'm not sure how else to structure my data.

Comment: Why don't you write your second node as order: 1: objA, 2: objC, 3: objB. You have all the info to do so (if I am not wrong)  and you will easily get the right order

Comment: I don't think that would solve the problem. I wouldn't have to order the data in the first call, but I'd still have to make the second call to get the referenced object, and it seems like those come back in an arbitrary order, not the order called. Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: If e.g. you store the ids of your objects in the order you desire (1=A, 2=C, 3=B), you first query the list of object Ids (which comes ordered) and then query your objects based on their IDs. This should do the trick, no?

Comment: But that's what I have now. The data is coming back ordered (because it's sorted by value, but you're right, it could just as easily be sorted by key if I flipped the data around like you suggest), but when I request the actual object in the second query, they come back out of order. I figured this was an async issue. Are they supposed to come back in the order I made the requests?

Comment: You will probably trigger several asynchronous calls for the second queries (e.g. Promise.all) and populate an array of objets ordered via your first query.

Comment: So I need to do the ordering on the client after they're all retrieved, and I know when they're all retrieved using Promise.all? This is an iOS app written in Swift. Isn't Promise.all a javascript thing?

Comment: Yes indeed Promise.all is javascript. I don't know about swift, but the logic I would use would be: a first query to get the order and build an array with object ids correctly ordered, then a set of queries (one for each object) which populate the array with the objects details at the right index for each object. Of course this is just a high level approach, based on my understanding and I haven't tried to implement it! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for data modeling with NoSQL databases is to structure your data in a way that suits your queries.  Since Realtime Database doesn't have server-side reverse ordering, you can still model your data to satisfy your requirements.  For example, instead of storing 1, 2, 3, you could store -1, -2, -3 (instead of, or in addition to what you're doing now), which will sort the way you want.  It's not uncommon to duplicate data like this in NoSQL databases.

Or you can switch to Firestore, which allows for specifying the direction of a sort of documents in a collection.